# undefined method `accountId=' for PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::Receiver

Tags: ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Using paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments 1.96.3 gem.

```
get_t = api.build_payment_details({:pay_key => payKey})
get_transaction_details_response = api.payment_details(get_t)
```

in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a issue in github to track the progress on this bug.

https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby/issues/2

Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks. I will report future issues on github.

Comment: Issue is fixed, please update the `paypal-sdk-core` gem to version `0.2.1`. If you are use bundler, just execute `bundle update paypal-sdk-core`